# ssrs 2008 default parameters to onother report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to pass parameters from one report on SSRS to another by using "Go to URL", however when the second report shows I have to re-select the parameters (they don't pull through). Do you have any suggestions?

I have researched this for the last 3 days and nothing is giving the result I require.

Comment: Why are you not using "Go to report" action and pass the current report parameters values to the second one?

Comment: Hi Mohamed it doesn't pass the parameters either can you post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the URL you're accessing is something like:

> http://SERVERNAME/reportserver?[PathToReport]&rs:Command=Render&Parameter1=[value]&Parameter2=[Value]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "**Go to report**" action and pass the parameter value from report 1 to the report 2.

The following screen shows how to pass parameter from report1 to report2 using "Go to report" action:

[image]